# Magento 2 - How to make responsive layout using child theme css?

Tags: magento2, layout, overrides, mobile-device

How to override styles-m css to set responsive layout? I just add custom blocks in footer area which are not responsive in mobile view. How to override styles-m in Luma child theme?

Thanks

[image]